# Why can't I update the apt Its because don't have a Virtual Box release file?

Tags: apt, updates, virtualbox, 20.04

I definitely think I've removed the virtual box perfectly. However, the following problems arise.

```
Hit:1 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Ign:6 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease         
Err:7 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.70.236.28 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`$ sudo apt update`

Even if I use the Ubuntu software update app, not the terminal, a system message of failure occurs. I tried to change to a best update server, but it also failed.

[image]

A similar question case has been reviewed, but no related case has been found with Virtual Box.

---

For reference, there are still two virtual boxes of related installation files left, but these could not be removed with the dpkg command.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                     Version      Architecture Description
+++-========================-============-============-========================>
un  virtualbox-guest-dkms    <none>       <none>       (no description availabl>
un  virtualbox-guest-modules <none>       <none>       (no description availabl>
```

Comment: It looks like you added arepository for VB. Try to remove the corresponding lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the list file(s) from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. (you need to use `sudo` to edit files there)

Comment: @dadexix86 The update problem is resolved because of you, Thanks. Could you tell me a little more about remove the dpkg(dkms) list on question?

Comment: They should already be removed, as you can see in the first column `un` = uninstalled. To double check this, you can use `apt policy virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-modules`

Comment: @dadexix86 But, why they'd viewing on dpkg list?

Comment: Since you did not post the command that you tiped, I cannot answer this question, sorry... It can be a lot of causes depending on what you asked the system for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file). If you try pointing your web browser at that repository (http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/) you will see that 'focal' is not listed, hence the 404 error.